# quadratic eigenvalue problem reformulation with eigenvalues on unit cycle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Suppose a quadratic eigenvalue problem is $$(A_2\lambda^2+A_1\lambda+A_0)x=0$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $x$ is the eigenvector. the quadratic form can be rewritten by
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&I\\
{{A_0}}&{{A_1}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
x\\
{\lambda x}
\end{array}} \right] = \lambda \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
I&0\\
0&{ - {A_2}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
x\\
{\lambda x}
\end{array}} \right]$$
Now, suppose $\lambda$ is restricted to eigenvalues on unit circles,i.e.,$\lambda  = \frac{{1 + i\sigma }}{{1 - i\sigma }}$. I want to further change the equation above as
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{ - I}&I\\
{{X_1}}&{{X_2}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
x\\
{\lambda x}
\end{array}} \right] = i\sigma \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
I&I\\
{{X_3}}&{{X_4}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
x\\
{\lambda x}
\end{array}} \right]$$
What should $X_{1,2,3,4}$ be?

Comment: I'm not sure why you call $\lambda$ an "eingenvalue" and $x$ and eigenvector

Comment: $\lambda$ is the nonlinear eigenvalue of the nonlinear eigenproblem, and $x$ is the corresponding nonlinear eigenvector

Comment: By using the Caley-transformation and using the characteristics: if $Ay = \lambda By$, then $\left( {A - B} \right)y = i\sigma \left( {A + B} \right)y$. one has ${X_1} = {A_0}$, ${X_2} = {A_1}+{A_2}$, ${X_3} = {A_0}$, ${X_4} = {A_1}-{A_2}$,